# How to decode a string UTF-8 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, nokogiri

I'm parsing an xml file in ruby (file.rb) but my output doesn't work properly even if I encode the string in UTF-8 or "ISO-8859-1". Any clue or can I set my encoding? [gist](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/e045498d572776405b41)

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'nokogiri'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_sentence
doc = Nokogiri::Slop <<-EOXML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<codeBook version="1.2.2" ID="klm-456-30">
     <var ID="V604" name="FHP_V145" wgt-var="K2" files="F1" dcml="0"
        intrvl="discrete">
          <qstn>
            <qstnLit>Dans quelle mesure cette aide vous a-t-elle
            &#195;&#169;t&#195;&#169; utile? &#195;&#8240;tait-elle
            :</qstnLit>
          </qstn>
    </var>
    <qstn>
</codeBook>
EOXML
  sentence = doc.children.css("[name=FHP_V145]").children.search("qstnLit").first.text.force_encoding("UTF-8").split("\n")
  sentence = sentence.map {|n| n.split.join(" ") }
  sentence = sentence.join(" ")
  puts sentence
    assert_equal(sentence, "Dans quelle mesure cette aide vous a-t-elle été utile? Était-elle :")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML seems to be corrupted. The entity of characters should be specified as follows.

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'nokogiri'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_sentence
doc = Nokogiri::Slop <<-EOXML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<codeBook version="1.2.2" ID="klm-456-30">
     <var ID="V604" name="FHP_V145" wgt-var="K2" files="F1" dcml="0"
       intrvl="discrete">
         <qstn>
           <qstnLit>Dans quelle mesure cette aide vous a-t-elle
           &#233;t&#233; utile? &#201;tait-elle
           :</qstnLit>
         </qstn>
     </var>
     <qstn>
</codeBook>
EOXML
  sentence = doc.children.css("[name=FHP_V145]").children.search("qstnLit").first.text.force_encoding("UTF-8").split("\n")
  sentence = sentence.map {|n| n.split.join(" ") }
  sentence = sentence.join(" ")
  puts sentence
    assert_equal(sentence, "Dans quelle mesure cette aide vous a-t-elle été utile? Était-elle :")
  end
end
```

If you cannot correct the XML, you can replace these entities to actual characters before reading it as follows. However &#8240; is incorrect. It should be &#137;

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'nokogiri'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_sentence
doc = Nokogiri::Slop <<-EOXML.gsub(/\&#([^;]+);/){[$1.to_i].pack('c')}
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<codeBook version="1.2.2" ID="klm-456-30">
     <var ID="V604" name="FHP_V145" wgt-var="K2" files="F1" dcml="0"
        intrvl="discrete">
          <qstn>
            <qstnLit>Dans quelle mesure cette aide vous a-t-elle
            &#195;&#169;t&#195;&#169; utile? &#195;&#137;tait-elle
            :</qstnLit>
          </qstn>
    </var>
    <qstn>
</codeBook>
EOXML

  sentence = doc.children.css("[name=FHP_V145]").children.search("qstnLit").first.text.force_encoding("ascii-8bit").split("\n")
  sentence = sentence.map {|n| n.split.join(" ") }
  sentence = sentence.join(" ")
  puts sentence
    assert_equal(sentence, "Dans quelle mesure cette aide vous a-t-elle été utile? Était-elle :")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri tries to do it’s best with encoding. Since it encounters `&#8240;`, which is apparently a [promille sign](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=8240), it assures an input text is `UTF-8`-ed. So far, it’s a default Nokogiri encoding.

In `UTF-8`, `&#195;` is `Ã` and `&#169;` is `©`. So, your output is *correct*. That said, your input is likely incorrect.